# Status of VideoCapture object in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have encapsulated the OpenCV VideoCapture class into a class of my own and am trying to initialize it from a video file on disk. The `.isOpened()` function returns **true**, but the frames I read later on are empty.

- If the `VideoCapture` can't read frames, why is it reporting being *open*?
- How can I further inspect the status of the VideoCapture object to find out why it's not reading frames?

Here is a tiny excerpt. `Init()` later throws an error because the frames read by `camera_.read()` are empty. **Better scroll through to the code at the bottom, it exemplifies the problem better.**

```
Camera::Camera(int target_width, int target_height, std::string filename)
    : target_width_(target_width),
      target_height_(target_height),
      camera_(filename)
{
    if (!camera_.isOpened()){
        cerr << "Failed to open video file" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    camera_.read(frame_full_);
    if (frame_full_.empty()){
       cerr << "Failed to read from video file" << endl;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Init();
}
```

**EDIT:**

So, reading from an actual webcam works fine, it is the code above (reading from a file by filename) that returns empty frames.

**EDIT2:**

So—as suggested by Mhd.Tahawi—my whole problem can be summarized by the code below:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("/Users/Me/Projects/whatev/some_video__640x360.avi");
cv::Mat test;

if (cap.isOpened()){
    cap.read(test);
    if (test.empty()) {
        std::cout << "BRO DO YOU EVEN CAPTURE?" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What camera are u using?

Comment: I am trying to read from a *file* to debug, the name `Camera` is perhaps a bit confusing. There are actually 2 constructors for `Camera`, corresponding to the 2 constructors for `VideoCapture` (using a camera device and a filename string).

Comment: did you try using the the `VideoCapture` object without using your wrapper class ? is it giving the same result ?

Comment: Does the reading from file too returns empty frames? I meant what is your camera device model? Sometimes it could be due to it not being compatible with opencv.

Comment: Yes. Reading from a file returns an empty frame. My webcam works fine.

Comment: i suspect codec problems - your code looks fine. (But double check if you really have a the correct filepath, even though it shouldn't say that it is open). if oyu are on windows you need "\\" in your path

Comment: Ok, yes, codec problems. I had to `brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg` . Thanks!

Comment: *considering moving my comment to an answer to improve my SO-Fame* ^^

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz : do it

Comment: At least SO has now a slightly higher percentage of answered questions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect codec problems - your code looks fine.

On a Mac, use `brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg` .

(But double check if you really have a the correct filepath, even though it shouldn't say that it is open). If you are on windows you need "\" in your path.